# Epilog error in new version

Tags: plotting, manipulate, warning-messages

I am able to run the following code in earlier versions and get what I want but version 12 gives an error message stating that **Coordinates should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form**.

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[0.4 + 0.001 x m, {x, 0, 1400}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1400}, {0, 1.8}}, 
    Epilog -> 
      {Red, 
        {Dashed, Line[{{x, 0}, {x, 0.4 + 0.001 x m}}]}, 
        {Dashed, Line[{{x, 0.4 + 0.001 x m}, {0, 0.4 + 0.001 x m}}]}, 
       Text[
         Style[TraditionalForm[{x, 0.4 + 0.001 x m}], Red, FontSize -> 12], 
         {x + .1, 0.4 + 0.001 x m + .1}]}, 
    ImageSize -> Large], 
  {{m, 1, "Slope"}, 0, 5}, {
  {x, 600, "Change in P & Q"}, 300, 1200}]
```

I have tried some tricks and codes, but no success.

Comment: The problem is that you have `x` as the independent variable in `Plot` *and* as a parameter in `Manipulate`.  That's causing a conflict.  Use a different variable inside the `Epilog` and use that same varaiebl for the `Manipulate`able variable.

Comment: Thanks, @march. I did work well. But what I don't understand is that the above code works nicely in earlier versions but not in the new version.

Comment: @march That's not exactly the conflict.  See my answer.  I believe `Plot` has changed, and what used to be okay no longer is.

Comment: To the close-voters: I fail to see how this is a simple mistake, and it is not explained in the documentation. IMHO, it should work as is; alternatively, WRI intentionally changed how `Plot` works, but did not update the docs.  (I can see how wrapping `PlotLabel` in `HoldForm` is an improvement, but it was a mistake to extend the rewriting to options like `Epilog`, imho.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A workaround is to `ReleaseHold` the plot.  `Plot` has gotten very complicated.  I don't really know what they are trying to address exactly.  Some of it has to do with data, `Quantity[]` etc.; some has to do with plot themes; and then there some other stuff I don't get.

Workaround:

```
Manipulate[
 ReleaseHold@
  Plot[0.4 + 0.001 x m, {x, 0, 1400}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1400}, {0, 1.8}}, 
   Epilog -> {Red, {Dashed, 
      Line[{{x, 0}, {x, 0.4 + 0.001 x m}}]}, {Dashed, 
      Line[{{x, 0.4 + 0.001 x m}, {0, 0.4 + 0.001 x m}}]}, 
     Text[Style[TraditionalForm[{x, 0.4 + 0.001 x m}], Red, 
       FontSize -> 12], {x + .1, 0.4 + 0.001 x m + .1}]}, 
   ImageSize -> Large], {{m, 1, "Slope"}, 0, 
  5}, {{x, 600, "Change in P & Q"}, 300, 1200}]
```

Note that is it not `Manipulate` and `x` being a `Manipulate` variable that is the problem.  It is `Plot`:

```
x = 600;
m = 1;
Plot[0.4 + 0.001 x m, {x, 0, 1400},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1400}, {0, 1.8}}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, {Dashed, 
    Line[{{x, 0}, {x, 0.4 + 0.001 x m}}]}, {Dashed, 
    Line[{{x, 0.4 + 0.001 x m}, {0, 0.4 + 0.001 x m}}]}, 
   Text[Style[TraditionalForm[{x, 0.4 + 0.001 x m}], Red, 
     FontSize -> 12], {x + .1, 0.4 + 0.001 x m + .1}]}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you remove the `Epilog`, the `Plot` works fine.  If you change the `Plot` variable in the function and iterator from `x` to `y`, it works fine.  It is as if someone decided that wherever the iterator variable appears in an option, it should be wrapped by `HoldForm[]`, because no one could possibly want to use the global value of the variable.  Maybe someone else can explain this, but it looks like a bug to me.

That said, using the same symbol in the same code for two purposes seems bad or confusing practice.

Comment: Instead of `ReleaseHold`, one can also `Evaluate` the `Epilog`: `Epilog -> { ..} // Evaluate`